# Amazon MWS Feed API returns error on order fulfillment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to update the order fulfillment status and i'm getting a following error from Amazon:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
      <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>XX</MerchantIdentifier>
      </Header>
      <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
      <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
          <AmazonOrderID>XX</AmazonOrderID>
          <FulfillmentDate>2017-03-13TH11:08:38Z</FulfillmentDate>
          <FulfillmentData>
            <CarrierCode>DHL</CarrierCode>
            <ShippingMethod>DHL</ShippingMethod>
            <ShipperTrackingNumber>XX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
          </FulfillmentData>
        </OrderFulfillment>
      </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

The resposne that im receiving is as follow:

```
                <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong with my xml that im sending? Ofc XX's are filled with real data in an actual xml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself - the culprit was the bad FulfillmentDate formatting.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the rare cases where the Amazon error description is almost spot on. Your items are not "invalid", they are simply missing from the feed. To be more specific, your XML is missing the `<Item>` structure(s) that must follow `<FulfillmentData>` :

```
...
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
           <AmazonOrderItemCode>ABC</AmazonOrderItemCode>
           <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Item>
      ... (repeat for each item in this delivery)
      <Item>
           <AmazonOrderItemCode>XYZ</AmazonOrderItemCode>
           <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
...
```

Comment: If you are confirming the entire order you do not have to provide the Items in your XML. The Items missing is not the issue here.

Comment: As above items field was not an issue.